# i have a Alphanumeric Range. and i have a number which will find in that range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Alphanumeric Range. range is

```
rohan143
ram 144
ramesh 123
mukesh149
```

now in another place when i write any number for example i write 123 it should return ramesh in another sheet.

[image]

Comment: Does name & number have to be in the same cell?  If it was number in column A and name in column B then a VLOOKUP formula would do it.  As it is I would say you could look for the space, but that won't work for `mukesh149` as there isn't a space between name and number. You could do a FIND on a partial match with 123, but that would also find 1234.

Answer (score 1):

In `Cell D3` enter the following formula

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP("*"&C3,A2:A5,1,FALSE),C3,""))
```

See image for reference.

[image]

***NOTE :*** If there is a cell with value say `abc1123` and that cell is above  `ramesh 123` then the result of this formula will be `abc1` and not `ramesh` because `"*"&"123"` also matches `abc1123` and will then replace `123` in `abc1123` with nothing () giving `abc1`.

Comment: It's Working.
Thanks bro

Comment: @ManishChaturvedi - If my solution solved your problem kindly accept it as answer by clicking tick mark at top left of answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses helper columns to split the name and number parts.  You can then do a `VLOOKUP` with the number as the key, and return the name without fear of the 123, 1123 problem alluded to in another answer.

The numbers are converted to "numbers" so as to make entries easier when you are entering a number.  `VLOOKUP` treats numbers, and text-that-looks-like-a-number differently.

To split the entries, use:

```
B2: =--MID(A2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A2&"0123456789")),99)
C2: =TRIM(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)))
```

[image]

To return the entry from a number, use a formula like (where your number is in `G4`):

```
H4:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]